# How to specify class types through interfaces in java

Tags: java

i hope you're doing great.

I am doing some exercises because i have exam on Saturday , and I found one exercise that is to build a selling system for (cups,spoon, etc  ) for coffe.

Alright , the first class is about Article , that has to be abstract, on this class are 2 attributes , model and price..but while i was reading the exercise i saw a text that was written " Article can be for Espresso or American Caffe " ,and this must be implemented through interface : type

So guys should i create a interface name Type and then inside of it create a enumeration or how , i have no idea.

```
public interface Type{
    public enum type{Espresso,American};
}
```

Am I correct or what do you guys think?
Thanks!!

Comment: The terminology is quite unclear. Why not post the actual instructions of the exercise?

Comment: Hello mate, it's on Albanian language, thats why I had a little problems translating it..

Comment: Sounds like you want a CaffinatedBeverage interface with Espresso and American implementations.  What is the different behavior between the two?  Sounds like a simple academic exercise with no real meaning beyond illustrating how to use interfaces.  It's a bad example.  Why not use the class Shape interface with getArea for subclasses Circle, Square, Rectangle, etc.?  Tell your instructor that their exercise is rubbish.

Comment: Hello again , I am asked to build a system to sell spoons , cups , and stuff  that relates to coffe , but the article has to be specified if it's for expresso coffe or american coffe , and that must be through interface "type" im really confused too..

Comment: The answer is it probably doesn't matter except for your assignment.  Part of the learning process is trying out your ideas and finding out if they work.  In the working world you do your best and find out if it works in production.  In academia you have to match what your instructor has in mind.  Give it a try.  You'll learn before or after you hand it in, but you will learn.

Comment: The type sounds like your model.  There will be a spoon for espresso and americano.  The language says you built that into the class name, not using an enum.  EspressoSpoon extends Article.

Comment: @duffymo i totally agree with you , and I personally like to figure things out by myself,  but I really can start this wrong , because it has to be extended on 5-6 other classes, and then everything will be wrong

Comment: My advice?  You should not be doing your homework here.  Feels like cheating to me.  Do your best and see what you get.

Comment: @duffymo my advice - Try to take things how you should , I just needed a hint , not all the exercise , I needed an advice for this , or a way to solve not the code...that was a little bit rude from you

Comment: @ValonJanuzaj - my advice is to not be so thin-skinned if you want to continue to use Stack Overflow.  Or anything else.  You will notice that I did give you a hint.  Either go and see where it takes you or ignore it.  I don't care which you do.